# What is the directory structure for adding Sorbet RBIs to a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sorbet

I have a [gem](https://github.com/adomokos/light-service) I want to add types to (either by submitting a PR or by forking to use just in my project), but [the documentation](https://sorbet.org/docs/rbi#rbis-within-gems) does not give any more guidance other than to create an `/rbi` folder.

Thinking out loud, should it mirror the files in `lib/` with added type signatures, or should it be one large file (per version?) like the signatures in [sorbet-typed](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet-typed/tree/master/lib)?

I don't know of any gems doing this yet, and the documentation doesn't mention it either.

Comment: *"I don't know of any gems doing this yet, and the documentation doesn't mention it either."* Of course [`sorbet`](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/tree/master/rbi) does this.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for that, I went so far as to look at tapioca but did not think to look at sorbet itself 

Answer (score 3):

I recently went through this process for one of my gems - pdf-reader. It was my first experience with sorbet (so I'm no expert), and I also noticed the lack of documentation for the specific use case of adding types to a gem.

I ended up generating the initial rbi file using [parlour](https://rubygems.org/gems/parlour), which put them all into a single file: https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/blob/480aa240a531cd6f97a46a29279f19025821e886/rbi/pdf-reader.rbi

Sorbet seems happy with that, so I haven't changed it.